# Residue of $\exp(\frac{k}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)})$ at $z=z_1$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

A residual integral problem has recently raised my curiosity and I do not seem to find a way out.

I am trying to find the value of the following integral
$$
\oint_{|z|=1} \exp\left(\frac{k}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}\right) \,dz,
$$
where $|z_1|<1<|z_2|$ and $k\ne 0$. However, finding the residue of $\exp\left(\frac{k}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}\right)$ at $z=z_1$ seems the hard step. I even tried the Taylor series of $\exp\left(\frac{k}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}\right)$ at $z=0$, but even finding the residue of $\frac{1}{(z-z_1)^n(z-z_2)^n}$ and summing them up leads to a nightmare. Does anyone have an idea how to tackle this integral? My prior gratitude to your valuable efforts.

P.S.

I appreciate a tight approximate for the aforementioned integral for $k>0$.

Comment: it is actually not hard to compute the residue by using the $m-1$ coefficient of the development of $1/(z-1)^m$ which is easily found; the final result should be expressed in terms of Bessel

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had achieved a series expansion for the final result of residue by splitting the $\exp$ into its Taylor series components, but I was unable to find a closed-form. Unfortunately, a Bessel function is a bit disappointing :) I guess, I should deviate to more approximate methods.

Comment: There are lots of well known approximations for the Bessel functions (a fast computation gave me the result as a combination of a Bessel function of index $1$ and one of index $0$ in terms of $k$ and $z_2-z_1$ so maybe that works for you

Comment: Hi.  I'm not sure if this helps, but it might facilitate analysis if one begins by using partial fraction expansion and writing $$\begin{align}
\exp\left(\frac{k}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}\right)&=\exp\left(\frac{k/(z_1-z_2)}{z-z_1}-\frac{k/(z_1-z_2)}{z-z_2}\right)\\\\
&=\exp\left(\frac{k/(z_1-z_2)}{z-z_1}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{k/(z_1-z_2)}{z-z_2}\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$Then, change coordinates to $w=z-z_1$ and integrate around $w=0$.

Comment: @Conrad, thanks. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @MarkViola, interesting insight. The problem is that the other exponential term ($\exp(-k\frac{z_1-z_2}{z-z_2})$) is nevertheless stuck to $\exp(-k\frac{z_1-z_2}{z-z_1})$, which enforces a non-trivial infinite series for the residue. However, another glimpse sparkled in my mind after reading your comment. This integral is the result of expressing a real integral $\int_0^{2\pi} f(\theta)d\theta$ in complex domain. Perhaps, transforming the contour from $|z|=1$ to something else, can untie the knot, at least, in the hope of finding an approximate. All the same, thank you for your time!